# Unable to run Clasp from npm or yarn script

Tags: google-apps-script, npm-scripts, clasp

I have a Google Apps Script project and I am trying to run `clasp push` from an npm or yarn script.  I am able to run `clasp push` from the command line, but the same command fails when used as a script:

```
"scripts": {
  "push": "clasp push"
}
```

When run as `npm run push` or `yarn push`, the script fails with the output `> Did you provide the correct scriptId?`.  If I run `clasp push` directly on the command line it successfully pushes my project files to Google Apps Script.

I have verified the script is executing in the same directory that contains .clasprc.json and appsscript.json.  Here is the full output:

```
> @ push /gs
> cd build && ls -a && clasp push

.               ..              .clasp.json     .clasprc.json   appsscript.json build.gs

> Did you provide the correct scriptId?

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ push: `cd build && ls -a && clasp push`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ push script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

For context, I am trying to do something similar to this blog post: https://labs.clio.com/a-modern-gmail-add-on-build-process-3dd7aad111f5

Comment: Is clasp installed locally or globally?

Comment: I have tried both local and global install, same results for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to diagnose the problem.  I found that I had a global login (~/.clasprc.json) that had a different access token from the local .clasprc.json.  When running `clasp push` from the command line, it uses the .clasprc.json file in the root of my project.  However when it runs through npm it was using the global login.
I ran `clasp logout` and verified the .clasprc.json file in the root of my project and my home folder were both deleted.  After logging back in again I was able to successfully push using the npm script

Answer (score 2):

Did you provide the correct scriptId?

- copy `.clasp.json` to build before run clasp.
- add the correct id to `.clasp.json`

Example

**shell**

```
$>  cd build && cp ./../.clasp.json ./ && ls -a && clasp push
```

**`.clasp.json`**

```
{
  "scriptId": "17qJJk9kvCm2abutL1MUNzfSUd9aeieJAGRdKF_4QG4-EkxQC5C6jHyIP",
  "rootDir": "build"
}
```

Comment: I was using webpack to copy .clasp.json as well as .clasprc.json to the build directory.  I am able to run `clasp push` from command line in that directory, just not through npm.  To simplify, I can reproduce the issue from the root of my project.  From NPM: ```$ npm run push /
> @ push /gs /
> clasp push /
> Did you provide the correct scriptId? ```   Direct from command line:
```$ clasp push /
└─ build/appsscript.json /
└─ build/build.gs /
Pushed 2 files.```

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the issue here:

1. Delete the ~/.clasprc.json file in the Global location.
2. Run `clasp login` to religion (Your Google account).
3. Run `clasp setup` to create a New spreadsheet and script project from the command line.
4. Then you can deploy it...

Hopefully, it might help.

For more, check this link: [From a Github Repo's ReadMe](https://github.com/KennStack01/React-Google-Apps-Script#-install-)